# C sockets - recv() and recvfrom() - write to memory using a specified modulo rather than sequentially?

Tags: c, sockets

Is there some option to have them write to memory using a specified modulo (in order to implement a circular buffer), rather than sequentially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use gather/scatter I/O with `recvmsg/sendmsg` where you can provide multiple memory regions to read/write from/to. For a ring-buffer you'd provide 2 regions, where the second region is the wrapped part.

That is less than ideal though, because your ring-buffer is still not contiguous and when your data/messages wrap you'd have to use `memmove` to unwrap it and make contiguous for functions that require contiguous memory (all standard library functions).

---

Another option is to use a "smart" ring-buffer: allocate memory for the buffer using `mmap` and map the same region of pages twice with no gaps in between. This way reading/writing past the end of the buffer continues reading/writing it from the start, preventing the discontinuity inherent when using a regular ring-buffer.

Linux-specific working example:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

typedef struct {
    size_t size;
    char* data;
} SmartRingBuffer;

#define PAGE_SIZE 4096

SmartRingBuffer SmartRingBuffer_create(size_t size) {
    // Round up to PAGE_SIZE.
    size = (size + (PAGE_SIZE - 1)) & ~(size_t)(PAGE_SIZE - 1);

    // Create a file to map.
    int fd = memfd_create("smart-ring-buffer", MFD_CLOEXEC);
    if(fd == -1)
        abort();
    if(ftruncate(fd, size))
        abort();

    // Reserve a contiguous region of memory twice the size, so that the second mmap with MAP_FIXED cannot fail.
    char* p = mmap(NULL, 2 * size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if(p == MAP_FAILED)
        abort();
    // Re-map the first half of the memory mapping over the second.
    char* p2 = mmap(p + size, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_FIXED, fd, 0);
    if(p2 == MAP_FAILED)
        abort();

    close(fd);

    SmartRingBuffer r;
    r.size = size;
    r.data = p;
    return r;
}

void SmartRingBuffer_destroy(SmartRingBuffer buf) {
    munmap(buf.data, buf.size * 2);
}

int main() {
    SmartRingBuffer buf = SmartRingBuffer_create(1);
    snprintf(buf.data, buf.size, "abc"); // Format into the 1st half.
    printf("%s\n", buf.data + buf.size); // Print the duplicate 2nd half.
    SmartRingBuffer_destroy(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

This is what the buffer looks like in `pmap -x <pid>` output:

```
Address           Kbytes     RSS   Dirty Mode  Mapping
00007f4c57154000       4       4       4 rw-s- memfd:smart-ring-buffer (deleted)
00007f4c57155000       4       4       4 rw-s- memfd:smart-ring-buffer (deleted)
```

Please note that `mmap` is rather expensive, so you may like to keep reusing `SmartRingBuffer`s as much as possible (keep them in a pool), rather than create/destroy it for each new connection.

Comment: Nice solution. This is however usable only if the size of the ring buffer is a multiple of PAGE_SIZE.

Comment: @DaBler True. However, your user-space receive buffer should be the same size as the kernel buffer, so that you can `recv` the entire kernel socket buffer in one call (and not cause starvation of other sockets by repeatedly calling `recv` until `EAGAIN` when using non-blocking I/O). And the default size of the kernel buffer is a few hundred kB by default.

Comment: I shall have to digest this, but I suspect it's a wonderful answer.

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin Can this be implemented in Windows too (perhaps by using CreateFileMapping() etc)?

Comment: @sid I am not familiar with Windows APIs, from the documentation it seems that you should be able to do that with `CreateFileMapping` instead of `memfd_create` and `MapViewOfFileEx` instead of `mmap`. Alternatively, you can use [WSL 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-index) to use Linux APIs on Windows. One important behaviour of `mmap` is that one can `mmap` over an existing mapping and it does the right thing and not fail. I don't know if `MapViewOfFileEx` can do that.

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin WSL doesn't support memfd_create, sadly :( Ah! you said WSL 2. I shall investigate!

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin I've been sketching some of this on paper. Am I correct in saying that with both the sendmsg/recvmsg method, and your smart method, the largest read/write to the buffers (in one shot) is the size of the buffer?

Comment: @sid You are right, for one shot read your buffer should be as big as the kernel socket buffer, plus the maximum unconsumed part that could possibly be in the buffer (i.e. `max_message_length - 1`), so that you can always pass the full buffer size as the argument to `recv`.

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin I meant a slightly different thing (although what you said was very helpful regardless). Imagine we're continuously writing to two iovec buffers, each of size `n`. We hop from one iovec buffer to the other and back again to perform the writes. If we find we suddenly have to write an amount of data > `n`, we must split this amount into a series of writes of max length `n`, or skip some data and write the last `n` bytes to the buffer. OR, because we have up to `2n` of space in the buffers, should we use this space to write in? Apologies for being unclear.